# Downgrade from default PHP 7.1 to PHP 7 on macOS High Sierra

Tags: php, macos, homebrew, php-7, php-7.1

I have a fresh installation of `macOS High Sierra` which comes with `PHP 7.1.16` (Build date: Mar 31 2018 02:53:20) installed. I would like to *downgrade* this to `PHP 7.0.27`.

`PHP 7.1.16` wasn't installed with `homebrew`, so I assume it's not as easy as removing it and installing `PHP 7` with `brew`.

What is the best and safest way to do this?

There's many resources to upgrade from PHP 7 -> 7.1 or 7 -> 7.2, but nothing to go the other way on macOS.

```
PHP 7.1.16 (cli) (built: Mar 31 2018 02:59:59) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
```

Comment: The safest way is not to uninstall or downgrade the system version; you'd be better off installing the other version through `MacPorts` or `Homebrew`

Comment: how about installing the specific version with brew? Also any specific reason you need to install PHP on osx itself?

Comment: @steros Yes, my application runs on PHP 7.0 in production and I need to be running the same version locally.

Comment: Any comments on the downvotes?

Comment: @crmpicco With application you're talking about a web application? Then better use something like vagrant or docker. See for example: puphpet.com for easy configuration.

Comment: @l'L'l Thanks. How do I switch from 7.1 to 7.0? The answer provided below suggests `update-alternatives`, but that doesn't exist on macOS.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution as far for my purposes was the shell tool "update-alternatives".

With that you should be able to switch between diffrent php versions dependently on your project.

So for example to switch to anohher php version set:

```
update-alternatives --set php=path to your php
```

Comment: So install PHP 7 with homebrew (`brew install php70`)? I noticed you were downvoted temporarily, can anyone explain why?

Comment: correct. Try to install each of your required php Versions and then depending on your project requirements switch to related php version. I had either some projects, which depends on diffrent php version... The better solution is an docker container.. but this is not your question.

Comment: yes, MacOS is doing it somewhat diffrently, anyway there is some workaround to enable the functionality: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/76704/how-to-set-alternatives-in-10-8